Why I usually get Attribute Error when I used to print head.next.val

# Definition for singly-linked list.

# class ListNode:

# def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):

# self.val = val

# self.next = next

from math import gcd
class Solution:
def insertGreatestCommonDivisors(self, head: Optional\[ListNode\]) -\> Optional\[ListNode\]:
current = head
print(current.next.val

Error :
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    print(current.next.val)


Plkease post a [mre].

Please fix the code formatting and syntax.

The error message is saying it.
